# Core Plot Hosting View Resizing

Tags: ios, core-plot

Is it possible to change the bounds and the position of the Hosting view after it has been assigned already. Changing the hosting frame to some other CGRect does not seem to be working ;hence the doubt or am I missing something.

Comment: Can you please share your code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely. The hosting view is a `UIView` like any other. The graph will automatically resize itself to fill the hosting view after any change.

Comment: Changed the hosting view frame and yes the graph resizes automatically. Thanks Eric.